# Running VirtualBox on server

Tags: linux, ubuntu, virtualbox

I'm trying to setup VirtualBox on a server, and I'm getting this response message when I try to start VBox service:

```
Mar 24 20:55:49 main vboxdrv.sh[4200]: vboxdrv.sh: Starting VirtualBox services.
Mar 24 20:55:49 main vboxdrv.sh[4242]: Starting VirtualBox services.
Mar 24 20:55:49 main vboxdrv.sh[4200]: vboxdrv.sh: Building VirtualBox kernel modules.
Mar 24 20:55:49 main vboxdrv.sh[4247]: Building VirtualBox kernel modules.
Mar 24 20:55:49 main vboxdrv.sh[4200]: This system is currently not set up to build kernel modules.
Mar 24 20:55:49 main vboxdrv.sh[4200]: Please install the Linux kernel "header" files matching the current kernel
Mar 24 20:55:49 main vboxdrv.sh[4200]: for adding new hardware support to the system.
Mar 24 20:55:49 main systemd[1]: vboxdrv.service: Control process exited, code=exited status=1
Mar 24 20:55:49 main systemd[1]: vboxdrv.service: Failed with result 'exit-code'.
Mar 24 20:55:49 main systemd[1]: Failed to start VirtualBox Linux kernel module.
```

It asks me to "Please install the Linux kernel "header" files matching the current kernel", but I'm not sure what should I install

Comment: Looking at my system you need `linux-headers-generic` (which installs the headers that match you current kernel). And IIRC you also need`dkms` (DKMS recompiles modules to match the current kernel).

Comment: I have already installed that, It didn't help

Comment: if you are using Ubuntu you should use their packages to install.  Remove whatever else you've installed,and install the `virtualbox` and `virtualbox-dkms` packages.  If you want the gui front end, it is `virtualbox-qt`

Answer (score 1):

In Debian you should look for a package named "linux-headers-$(something)", where $(something) is the kernel version and build. In other distro like Ubuntu, this may be different (I think it's called "linux-generic").

Comment: I also installed that and still getting same error message

Comment: Did you installed gcc and all the dev stuff?

Comment: I'm running Ubuntu 18.04LTS, forgot to mention that

Comment: It's installed (gcc), what do you mean by 'other dev stuff'? I have installed following:
- build-essential
- linux-generic
- linux-headers-generic

Comment: If you can build a generic C program, you should be ok. Which version of VirtualBox are you installing? It's stated to install on Ubuntu 18?

Comment: It's VirtualBox 5.2 on Ubuntu 18.04LTS

Comment: If you downloaded the package from the official repository, the system should have choosen the right version. Tell us the steps you have made to install Virtualbox: did you added the proper line to "/etc/apt/sources.list"?

Answer (score -1):

I got it fixed by following Scaleway's guide on GitHub.

https://github.com/scaleway/kernel-tools